# Use javascript to find email address in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am trying to do is to extract email address out of the string `SomeName, First (First.SomeName@usa.mywebsite1.com)`

Here is the code that I already tried:

```
 var stringToSearchIn="SomeName, First (First.SomeName@usa.mywebsite1.com)";


 var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

var extractedEmail=re.exec(stringToSearchIn);
```

The variable extractedEmail in the code returns a null.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312662/regex-for-email-matching

Comment: If the string is always in this format, why not just use `(` and `)` as delimiters? No need for a regex then.

Comment: @Jay That's a useless edit now, as someone can always retrieve this question's history.

Comment: I had changed the email address before posting it. That email address was non existent.

Comment: Next time, when you want to use a fictive email adress, let it end with `@example.com`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I tried this and failed

...is not a very useful description of what happenned. At a guess, the re failed to find a match. An obvious cause for this is the regex you've used here will only match a string which *ONLY* contains an email address - remove the end anchors (^,$) from the regex and you'll get your email address.

```
var re = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;
```

Comment: @Foo: You can just use `extractedEmail[0]`.

Comment: Sorry guys, cannot up vote answer due to lack of reputation points :(

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regex here. If the string is always of the format

```
Name (email)
```

You can simply use `(` as delimiter:

```
var stringToSearchIn="SomeName, First (First.SomeName@usa.mywebsite1.com)";

var extractedEmail = stringToSearchIn.substr(stringToSearchIn.indexOf('(') + 1).slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
var searchInThisString ="SomeName, First (First.SomeName@usa.mywebsite1.com) SomeName2, First2 (First2.SomeName2@usa.mywebsite1.com)";

var foundEmails =[];

var emailRegex = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;

var gotcha;

while (match = emailRegex.exec(searchInThisString)){

     //-- store in array the found match email
     foundEmails.push(match[0]);

    //-- remove the found email and continue search if there are still emails
    searchInThisString= searchInThisString.replace(match[0],"")
}
```

alert(foundEmails.join(" "))

Comment: Who is `gotcha` and why is `match` global?

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex

```
@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"
```

This will accept any of the following:

- email@email.com
- email@email.email.com
- email@email.email.email.com

and so on...

Comment: I haven't tested to see if this works, and I'm not going to. It could be a very useful regex, but you haven't explained at all *why* this could be a very useful regex.

Comment: It won't solve the OP's problem and there are multiple issues with the validation of the address using this - it will only match something which looks vaguely like an email address