# Validate email address using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

here's the code that I'm using to validate email address on clicking submit button by the user,

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(EmailID);
```

I would like to allow apostrophe(') to the email address entered by the user, what would be the modification for the regex above?

Comment: See http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html Anything less than that is imperfection. In other words, it's very hard to validate _all_ variations of valid email addresses.

Comment: The best way to validate an e-mail address is to try it. As long as it has an @ symbol it could be an e-mail address.

Comment: There is certainly a HUGE gap between the regex offered here and the one Rick Visconni recommends. Your regex is broken in several regards Keethan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use javascript to find email address in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140955/use-javascript-to-find-email-address-in-a-string)

Comment: I recommend using Validator - https://github.com/chriso/validator.js, email address syntax is impossibly complicated and this library accounts for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/^(\w|')+([\.-]?(\w|')+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

it will allow apostrophe anywhere before the '@'

Answer (score 1):

Your current Regex match the following email address :

- test@provider.com
- test-user@provider.com

But doesn't match this :

- test-user-name@provider.com

If you're just basically trying to validate an email adress containing one apostrophe like this one :

- test'username@provider.com

Then just add a quoi in the first bracket :

```
/^\w+(['.-]?\w+)@\w+([.-]?\w+)(.\w{2,3})+$/
```

But it still won't match A LOT of email addresses (one with a dash and an apostrophe, one with multiples dash [...]).

Comment: Why do you think 'that test-user-name@provider.com' wont match? if you try the regex, you'll see it will. the ([\.-]?\w+) capture group has a star, so it could be repeated as many times as need be. it won't match this however: 'test-user-@provider.com'

Comment: @hhamilton He actually edited the Regex, it was something else at first

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions is probably the best way. Here's an example [(demo):](http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/19)

```
function validateEmailAddress(emailID) { 
    var emailRgx = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return emailRgx .test(emailID);
}
```