# Using JavaScript and Regex to extract 1 specific data from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get from an URL like these JUST the "test@gmail.com" (or whatever email will be in the URL) :

- www.website.com/?email=test@gmail.com
- www.website.com/?email=test@gmail.com&name=john
- www.website.com/?name=john&email=test@gmail.com

My problem is to solve that **all of these 3 cases can happen** (so *no* other data, OR data *after* the email, OR data *before* the email).

Unfortunately I have zero Regex-Skills, but was able to get so far together these 2 things:

```
/email=(.*)/
/email=(.*)\&/
```

The 1st one works if the email is the ONLY data.
The 2nd one works just if there is another data after my email.

But as mentioned I need to make it work regardless of which of the 3 types above is the case.

Could you help me out please?

Thank you very much!

BTW, I need it for this:

```
var msg = window.location.href.match(/email=(.*)/);
```

(I'm searching for an answer for more than 2 hours, used Google, used Regex-Testers, checked out Cheat Sheets and read many StackOverFlow-Questions... But I can't solve it on my own.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for email matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312662/regex-for-email-matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: https://regex101.com/r/gMyqDa/1
It matches email patterns not just any characters after `email=`

Comment: Thank you, but this has been deleted (and I think I deleted it, as I see now that you gave me a delete-link... :) )

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! Fixed. :)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much yBot! I implemented this in my site and it's working fine :) Thats a much easier approach than my tries

Answer (score 0):

if your cases are that simple, then just exclude the ampersand

```js
var urls = [
"www.website.com/?email=test@gmail.com",
"www.website.com/?email=test@gmail.com&name=john",
"www.website.com/?name=john&email=test@gmail.com"
];

for (i in urls) {
  var url = urls[i];
  console.log(url);
  console.log(url.match(/email=[^&]+/)[0]);
}
```